# How can I force an outer div to expand to height of inner div?

Tags: css, height

I have data that is ajaxed in to `<div class="content">`. I want the outer div to expand to the height of the inner div. I can't figure out how to do this.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">Stuff goes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 740px;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 335px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.content {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 7px 0;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

I want the outer div to expand to the height of whatever is inside `<div class="content"></div>`. How can I do this?

Comment: I haven't used javascript because I assumed there is a way to achieve this by only using CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you use POSITION in your CSS. Remove the POSITION from the INNER class and the OUTER div will expand correctly. Perhaps you could use margins to position you inner div.

EDIT:

Here is a possible alternate CSS for you. It may or may not be appropriate for you requirements.

```
.outer {
    width: 740px;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top:70px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.inner {
    width: 335px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.content {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 7px 0;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thaaannnkkk you. I've been fighting with this for a half an hour now. I had set the position on the inner div. Never again.

Answer (score 1):

The position:absolute in the inner div is the main problem. Here is an example with positions removed, note you need to add the nbsp; to the outer div to show.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>

.outer {
    width: 740px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    background:#F90;
}

.inner {
    margin:70px 0 0 10px;
    width: 335px;
    bottom: 0;
    background:#9FF;
}

.content {
    display:block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 7px 0;
    text-align: left;
    background:#CCC;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="outer">&nbsp;
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">Stuff goes here. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to resize the outer div. Put this into the callback of your AJAX request:

```
    var $inner = $('.inner');
    var height = parseInt($inner.height()) + parseInt($inner.css('top'));  
    $('.outer').css('height', height);
```

Assuming that you use jQuery, that is...

Comment: Thumbs down for the javascript suggestion...lame

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks a lot!!! But please explain the code here, the 2nd line is confusing