# How to make my container grow accordingly to its containers inside him?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My problem is this. I have container and inside him i have 2 more containers one of the containers i use to put image and other container i use to put header and paragraphs. I want to make something like short preview of a news and i will have multiple copies of this containers with different images and different headers and paragraph and i don't want to always adjust the height of the parent container i want to automatically adjust his height. Can i do that with CSS and how ?

Here is example code

```
<!-- First div is Bootstrap jumbotron -->
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="boxForNews">
      <div class="boxForImage">
         <img src=" ">
      </div>
      <div class="boxForContent">
         <h3>Some Heading</h3>
         <p>Random text Random text Random text Random text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS

```
.boxForImage{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
.boxForContent{
    width:66%;
    float:left;
}
```

The containers inside boxForNews are growing accordingly to the elements i put inside them but their parent do not grow accordingly to the grow of the 2 containers and my jumbotron gets broken because of this.

I Could give the first container some height but i the content i put inside the 2 containers inside him will always change and i will have to always play and change the height for every news i add.

Comment: Similar type of question has been asked earlier also: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522093/how-can-i-force-an-outer-div-to-expand-to-height-of-inner-div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the errors in the code; You are missing an end quoation mark for the class attribute `boxForImage`, and the style rule `.boxForImage` ends with `{` instead of `}`.

The floating elements in the `boxForNews` div won't affect the height of their parent. You can make it contain its children by changing the `overflow` style:

```css
.boxForImage{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
.boxForContent{
    width:66%;
    float:left;
}

.boxForNews {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!-- First div is Bootstrap jumbotron -->
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="boxForNews">
      <div class="boxForImage">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>
      <div class="boxForContent">
         <h3>Some Heading</h3>
         <p>Random text Random text Random text Random text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```